# Animate image from top to bottom on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I'm trying like this : http://demo.highthemes.com/smartscreen/ on right corner image link tabs are there..On hover its animating and changing the color..Anyone can help on this?

Comment: Please post the code whatever you tried

Comment: I need the code for that:)

Comment: @DeneshKumar until and unless you show your efforts. nobody going to help you. infact question will be closed soon

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this..if anyone could help me to achieve that concept,it will be more appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a good starting point for a jQuery solution:

```
$(".on-hover-show-whatever").on('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(this).find('.whatever').slideDown(250);
  } else {
    $(this).find('.whatever').slideUp(250);
  }
});
```

Look at this **jsFiddle** here: [A little fiddle I did](http://jsfiddle.net/knh7z/)

Other than that you could just use a pure CSS solution with :hover and [CSS animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/).

Comment: Thanks for your response:):), will try it out